# como seteo un valor de session en un label

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, session

tengo una variable de session almacenada, como podría setearla en un label?
estoy trabajando con asp.net y c#.

Cualquier ayuda la agradecería mucho

Comment: en que accion quieres aplicarla? porque usar la session si pudiste asignarla no veo porque no puedes usarla, hay algo raro en la pregunta, pudes asignar la Session pero porque no puedes usarla si es casi lo mismo

Comment: no se como es la sintaxis para ponerla en un label directamente si debo usar algun caracter especial para ponerla en el html.aspx (la tengo en el html.aspx.cs)

Comment: como asignaste el valor al Seccion? hablamos de un control label de asp.net, no?

Answer (score 1):

esto te podria ayudar.

Dentro de la etiqueta <%# ____ %> llamas la variable de session

PD: Lo que no se es a que te refieres con setearla, ya que set es modificar, y get es obtener. Quieres obtener o modificar la variable de Session. mi ejemplo es para obtener el dato alamacenado en esta variable, ahora si quieres modificar esa variable me avisas.

Saludos

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflow.test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="FORM_TEST" runat="server">
        <div>
             <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["TEST"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["TEST"] = "variableSession";
            lblTest.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```